# Calling member constructor in class definition

Tags: c++, c++11

```
struct Foo
{
    std::vector<int> vec = {5, 123};
};
```

The above code initializes the vector with two elements (5 and 123). How can I call the constructor that takes size and initial value - the equivalent of `std::vector<int> vec(5, 123)`.

Comment: what's wrong with `vec(5, 123)`?

Comment: @Default It does not work in class definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this form, for which the `std::initializer_list` constructor does not participate in overload resolution:

```
std::vector<int> vec = std::vector<int>(5, 123);
```

Comment: Is this guaranteed to call the constructor and not the copy constructor? I ask because my embedded compiler issues a warning when I use this syntax for classes that have a deleted copy constructor.

Comment: @rozina In your example, the copy constructor is not deleted. In general, no copying should take place due to copy elision. But this still requires the type to be copyable, which is why it should fail (not warn, fail) if the type isn't copyable.

Comment: So lets say I have a class with deleted copy constructor and a constructor that takes two ints and a constructor that takes std::initializer_list<int>. How would I call the constructor with two ints in the class definition?

Comment: @rozina AFAIK, you could only do that if your class has a move copy constructor. But now you're asking a different question. Look at the question you actually asked. I am providing an answer to that one.

Comment: I made an edit to the question. You are correct though, I did not ask directly what I was interested in, since I was not sure how to ask it at first :)